# JQuery Click Event Not Working Correctly

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I have the following scripts in the `<head>` section of my website:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('#submit').click(function() {
$('#submit').css('background-image', 'url("/static/ui/msback.png")');
});
</script>
```

And a submit button with the `id` of `submit`. However, clicking on the submit button will not change the background image.
What is the error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your function withtin `.ready()` so that jQuery will assign the Function to the button after the element is loaded. Otherwise jQuery cannot assign the function to any button as the button does not exist yet.

Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("/static/ui/msback.png")');
    });
});
```

**JS FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/pQgAj/1/

See also http://api.jquery.com/ready/ for more detailed information.

**And**: you can use `$(this)` within the `.click()` function, saves time as jQuery does not have to evalute the `$('#submit')` again.

//*Alternative*: An alternative to wrapping your function into `.ready()` is to place your javascript code at the end of your site. But I do not recommend this.

Comment: Thanks. Both tips were useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

try to wrap it within document.ready:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function() {
          $('#submit').css('background-image', 'url("/static/ui/msback.png")');
        });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Using `$('#submit')` within the `.click()`  function is not needed here. Better use `$(this)` as the click function does pass the triggering element.